# Excel sum based on lookup of code and values in another table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, excel-2016

Given 2 named tables in Excel 2013 (or higher):

**tblInvoice**

```
ID    InvRef    Total
1     I/123        45
2     I/234         8
```

**tblDeliveries**

```
ID    InvRef    Amt
1     I/123      10
2     I/123      15
3     I/123      20
4     I/234       5
5     I/234       3
```

How can we get the `tblInvoice[Total]` to compute automatically using an Excel formula? i.e. in pseudocode:

```
 tblDeliveries[Total] = SUM(tblDeliveries[Amt] WHERE MATCH InvRef)
```

I have tried this Excel formula in `tblInvoice[InvTotal]` but it is returning an incorrect value:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(tblDeliveries[InvRef],[InvRef],tblDeliveries[Amt]))
```

Also tried swapping the first and second parameters. Produces a different amount, but still incorrect:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF([InvRef],tblDeliveries[InvRef],tblDeliveries[Amt]))
```

If relevant, it is assumed that there is a 1:N relationship from `tblInvoice[InvRef]`:`tblDeliveries[InvRef]` and that `tblInvoice[InvRef]` is UNIQUE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect for what you require.

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(tblDeliveries[InvRef],[@InvRef],tblDeliveries[Amt]))`

The @ is the crucial difference.

Regards

Comment: I am not used to table references.  Can you explain what the @ does?

Comment: It instructs the formula to look at the value in the referenced column within the same row as that in which the formula resides. Without it, you are referencing the entire column.